# postgresql - Get query rows and plan from Postgres EXPLAIN ANALYZE query

Tags: sql, postgresql, validation

I am currently trying to get the rows returned by the query and along with some metrics like query complexity for validating query correctness and efficiency. Is there a way that I can get both the rows and the query plan without having to the run the query twice?

I have seen this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116834/how-to-get-row-count-diagnostic-after-explain-analyze-in-postgres) on dba exchnage but I'm unsure if it is possible to get the rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this is by loading auto_explain with

- `LOAD 'auto_explain';`
- `SET auto_explain.log_analyze=true;`
- `SET auto_explain.log_min_duration=0;`

This way, the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` plan gets printed into the log, and you get your query results in the client. Note these steps will only activate auto_explain for your session. If you want a global auto_explain, you will need to update your `postgresql.conf`

More info in the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: Thanks for the response! By default my logs are set to `stderr`, does that mean if I run a normal query `SELECT * FROM ...` the query plan should be emitted to `stderr`?

Comment: Yeah then it’ll go to `stderr`

Comment: You have to set `client_min_messages = log` to get the plan on the console.